# How to handle an update of many docs in a single query in Elasticsearch and Python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, db2

I'm working in a Python script which in simple terms it will update the stock field of every document when his _id matches with the Id that I get from
a DB2 query, in this query I bring two columns: `catentry_id` and `stock`. So the idea is to find every single id from DB2 in every single document of ES and update the stock from DB2 to ES.

I new int the world of ES and I did many searches and read many sites and also the documentation looking a way to handle this

I try first to get all the docs of the index using this querys i have to put in a obj in the python for nex iteration with the resultset from db2.

```py
GET /_search
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["_id","stock"],
        "excludes": ["_index","_score","_type","boost","brand","cat_1","cat_1_id",\
                    "cat_1_url","cat_2","cat_2_id","cat_2_url","cat_3","cat_3_id",\
                    "cat_3_url","cat_4","cat_4_id","cat_4_url","cat_5","cat_5_id",\
                    "cat_5_url","category","category_breadcrumbs","children",\
                    "children_tmp","delivery","discount","fullImage","id","keyword",\
                    "longDescription","name","partNumber","pickupinstore","price",\
                    "price_internet","price_m2","price_tc","product_can","published",\
                    "ribbon_ads","shipping_normal","shortDescription","specs",\
                    "specs_open","thumb","ts","url"]  
    },
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "stock": {
                "gte": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know the way to create the proper query to update all the docs. I was thinking to try to do it in a script with `painless` or `_bulk`, but I didn't find any example or anyone who does a similar task.

**Update:**

I could solve the taske with the guidelines of the netx [link](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-python-to-update-api-elasticsearch-documents-259#), but for my case this take aprox 20 min to update all the doc in elastic.

First i try to solve the upde with bulk o parallel bulk but then i figure out the bulk's update all the source and i doesnt work with painless script, if im wrong about what i said may be i couldnt made it work.

Second i try to compare only the values of the stock that have difference between DB2 and ES and that reduce me a lot of time, but for some reason im  not 100% there is updating the correct amount of docs.

And the last craizy thing i try to doit was to pass the last dictionary inside of a painless script as a param and iterate inside the script, but that didn't work, as I'm new to this and I read about painless syntax is similar to groovy I try to iterate the dictionary as a map again didn't work where the API throws a syntax error.

I would like to optimize this but my sprint finished last week and now I have another tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is really not my day, I had 9 tabs open, how much experience do you have with parsing and python in general? maybe I am just wasting your time, but your project sounds fun and if you want to share code live I got some hours free now.

Comment: Really python i not my main skill, so what im doing is researching and developing at the same time.

By the way in my script i import the elastic search helpers.

`code`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch,helpers

Comment: I think i found a way to give solution to my task.
[link](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-python-to-update-api-elasticsearch-documents-259)